# epoll: What is appropriate behavior, when I get EPOLLOUT and EPOLLHUP in the same event?

Tags: c, linux, nginx, epoll

First time `epoll()` user. I'm using `epoll` to write a simple HTTP client, to connect to an nginx Web server on a host I control.

Here is this sequence of events I am looking at

1. I shutdown the (server) host
2. I start my client, which does `socket()`, `epoll_create1()`, `epoll_ctl()`, `connect()`, `epoll_wait(EPOLLOUT)` which I believe to be correct
3. I startup the host
4. Once the web server starts up, `epoll_wait()` completes and returns one event.

Usually, the event returned by `epoll_wait()` is just `EPOLLOUT`. However, every 5th try or so, I get `EPOLLOUT|EPOLLHUP`. And I'm not sure what to do.

Is this proper by `nginx`? Does `EPOLLOUT|EPOLLHUP` even make sense?
Should I just ignore the `EPOLLHUP`, and just `send()` my data and check the return value? It feels strange to ignore a `HUP` ... but I am new to `epoll` and for all I know this stuff happens all the time.

All I want the client to do, is to send a plain ole HTTP GET request, and then recv the response.

Thanks!

### Edit

Completely rewrote this question since the initial posting. If that is not SO-approved, my apologies.

Comment: @kfx thanks. Added some more detail; hope that helps.

Comment: Just rewrote the whole question, which makes the @kfx question look impertinent

Comment: Starting the client with no server running does not make sense. Does `connect` succeed at all? I would be surprised if it did, since that's not possible at all.

Comment: `connect()` succeeds (it's a non-blocking socket).

Intentionally starting a client while the server is coming up, might (in special cases) make sense. However I am more concerned with the case, where my client starts, and unbeknownst to me the server is in the process of restarting. With a client on a scheduler, hitting multiple unreliable servers, this is not unforseeable.

Comment: You could run a `tcpdump port …` to see if the unusual combination `EPOLLOUT|EPOLLHUP` goes along with special data traffic.

Answer (score 2):

By experimentation, I found that enabling EPOLLOUT on a socket that's just been created, before connect() is called, fires the EPOLLOUT | EPOLLHUP events. What I did was to do a connect() first, verify that it returns EINPROGRESS and then enable EPOLLOUT.